# Is my Rigowksi Coil turns calculation correct and how to calculate the sensitivity?

Tags: design, inductance, coil

First, I would like to show my calculation. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Suppose the maximum induced voltage in the coil is 250mV and the current to be measured is maximum 1000 A.

So, the current  equation is:

[image: Current]

Suppose the dimension of my coil is:

a=16.5 mm
b=32 mm

According to this formula:

[image: Coil]

[image: Mutual]

[image: Calc]

I want to calculate how many windings I should make. The result is:

N = 353 turns

So, am I correct? Or did I make a mistake?

Then, how to calculate the sensitivity?
Can I just simply divide 250mV/(1000*sqrt(2) A) ?

Comment: Will built one with your calculation and share results after measures.
I first will recalculate as per your statements. Wondering where you took the formulae from.
Have read almost 15 papers over the topic but this is the first with a practical approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not a "real answer" yet.
It may become one.
But hopefully still useful.
I'm getting around to getting around to playing with Rogowski coils as part of a larger project.

The internet is full of references as you know doubt know, but

Should be close to what is wanted [DESIGN AND CALIBRATION OF ROGOWSKI COILS](http://projects.npl.co.uk/power_energy/docs/7%20Design%20and%20Calibration%20of%20Rogowski%20Coils.pdf)

This looks extremely good - despite the "relaying" focus:
IEEE PSRC Special report 2010 - [Practical Aspects of Rogowski Coil
Applications to Relaying](http://www.pes-psrc.org/Reports/Practical%20Aspects%20of%20Rogowski%20Coil%20Applications%20to%20Relaying_Final.pdf)

More specific [Design of a PCB Rogowski Coil based on the PEEC Method](http://www.hpe.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethpublications/Rogowski_Coil_02.pdf)

---

Just for fun - [Lightning measurement!!!](http://www.lightning-measurement.com/3-8.html) with a Rogowski coil.